# Office 365 pre-provision my site issue with Powershell

Tags: powershell, client-object-model, office-365, user-profile, onedrive

I am creating personal sites using powershell csom.

My issue is on below line

```
$loader = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.ProfileLoader]::GetProfileLoader($ctx)
```

I get following error.

> ```
> $loader = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.ProfileLoader]::GetProfileLoader($ctx)
> ```
>
> Cannot convert argument "context", with value:
>
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext", for "GetProfileLoader" to type
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext": "Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext" value of type
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext" to type
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext"."

Comment: Did you load "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles"? Also, You must use Windows PowerShell 3.0. If you use SharePoint 2013 Management Shell, the script will fail.

Comment: yes userprofile.dll is loaded. I am following this source code https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-get-User-Profile-262fd67b . I am able to get clientcontext so i think powershell version is OK for 2013 online

Comment: Can you try using LoadWithPartialName syntax for loading dll instead of Add-Type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into the same issues and it turned out I was referencing the wrong DLLs. I was also having issues with `CreatePersonalSiteEnqueueBulk` not being recognized.

I was referencing the 15 version not the 16 version and also the 16 version I had was out of date. Be sure you are referencing the proper DLL and have the most up to date version. I'm now running 16.0.3104.1200 and these issues went away.